# Do non-neutral plasmas follow a Maxwell-Boltzmann energy distribution in ion traps

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, plasma-physics

Ion traps are interesting, and when thinking about them, I was wondering about this.

- Non-neutral plasmas or just ions interact through Coulomb interactions rather than 2 body collisions. So, does the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution still apply?
- Since, in ion traps, electric and magnetic fields exist, how would this affect the energy distribution of the ions?
- And if the ions were to escape the ion trap, will this happen if the particles' kinetic energy ( Thermal energy or random kinetic energy) is greater than the potential energy needed to cross the barrier? I was wondering if we could use the ideal gas equation, PV=nRT, to calculate the pressure arising from temperature, and then add it to the pressure due to Coulomb interactions. Is this right?

Thanks

Comment: If the ion-ion Coulomb collision rate is high enough (i.e., larger than, say, the ion cyclotron frequency) then a Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution can be present, yes.  However, the effectiveness of the collisions to maintain such a distribution is highest at the lowest energies (in the plasma rest frame), so tails may arise.  In an ion-only plasma, the unshielded electric fields would likely cause problems with the above model though.

Comment: So, the Maxwell-Boltzmann won't apply if the plasma is hot? So, what distribution will the particles resort to?

Comment: No, it's not really about being "hot" or "cold."  My comment was that Coulomb collisions would only be able to dominate over a certain range of energies, which would be relative to the distribution.  This is all assuming the thermal speed is very non-relativistic, of course.